# Change the color of image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am beginner in OpenCV, I have change the color of image using `ColorMap` function, and I also learn how to make own `custom colorMap` using Lookup Table.
My problem is I have a color palette using mouse I click on the color palette and select any color from that. I want to change the color of the image with the color I have selected. Can Anyone tell me how to do this.If anyone need the code for custom colormap comment below I will provide the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you attach sample input and expected output ?

Comment: i have tried to upload the image but i am not able to do this sorry

Comment: Basically what i want is that when i click on any part of palette the color of the grayscale image to that color. Same as done in ColorMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ColorMap` does not change the color of image with just one color. It changes the color of the image according to their depth value, That's what I think.

This process is known as pseudo coloring where using other image you are changing the color of your original image.

In `OpenCV` you can achieve this using `Lookup Table` and `LUT` function.

I am providing you the sample code for that, where I have a palette and a grayscale image.

Code of pseudo coloring:

```
cvtColor(im.clone(), im, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
uchar b[256], g[256], r[256];
int i = 0;
for (double x = 1; x <= palette.rows; ) {

    b[i] = palette.at<Vec3b>(x, palette.cols / 2)[0];
    g[i] = palette.at<Vec3b>(x, palette.cols / 2)[1];
    r[i] = palette.at<Vec3b>(x, palette.cols / 2)[2];
    i++;
    x += 3.109; 
}
Mat channels[] = { Mat(256,1, CV_8U, b), Mat(256,1, CV_8U, g), Mat(256,1, CV_8U, r) };
Mat lut;
cv::merge(channels, 3, lut);
Mat color;
cv::LUT(im, lut, color);
```

That's working correct for me.

The basic logic behind that is first of all I have covert the grayscale image to Bgr. Then I have read the pixel of value of the color palette and store that in array. And through this array I have created a lookup Table that store that values using `merge` function. And using that lookup table and `LUT` function I have just put that values of lookup table into my new `Mat` variable i.e `color`

**Note:** I have incremented `x` according to my need because my palette height is `800`. So just to take 256 input or less I have incremented `x` by `3.109`

Hopefully that helps.